# Search for a word inside a macro using expl3

Tags: counters, expl3, latex3, strings

The title of this question refers to words in a general sense but in my particular case I'm searching for numbers inside a previously defined macro. In that macro I have only numbers separated by spaces. I would like to search inside `\teststr` for a number stored in a counter, e.g.:

```
\newcounter{testx}
\newcounter{testy}
\def\teststr{ 1 2 3 4 5 9 10 11 30 }
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {NVV}
\cs_new:Npn \test #1#2#3{
 \int_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_int {#2}
 \seq_set_split:NVV \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_int {#1}
 \int_set:cn {c@#3} {(\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq) -1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The `\test` macro should be invoked the following way:

```
\test{\teststr}{\value{testx}}{testy}
```

In the following example, the counter `testy` stores the number `1`. That's the expected behavior.

```
\setcounter{testx}{4}
\test{\teststr}{\value{testx}}{testy}
```

Now, `testy` should contains `0` as its value. Also it works:

```
\setcounter{testx}{6}
\test{\teststr}{\value{testx}}{testy}
```

But with `1` doesn't behaves as I would wish:

```
\setcounter{testx}{1}
\test{\teststr}{\value{testx}}{testy}
```

it stores `4` because `\teststr` contains four occurrences of `1`, that's right but I would like to search like searching 'words', i.e. with spaces before and after the search pattern.

I did test with `_tl` and `_str` variable types on second arg of `\seq_set_split` without success.

Any help would be appreaciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are not very clear what you want the code to do, it would likely be more efficient and simpler if you used a seq or clist rather than a space separated list, expl3 has functions provided out of the box to test if a value is a member of a  seq

Comment: In simpler words, you want to count the occurrences of a specific number in your string? For instance, if the test string is `1 2 1 2 3 2 4`, looking for `1` should return 2 and looking for `2` should return 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\regex_count:nnN`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{testx}
\newcounter{testy}
\def\teststr{ 1 2 3 4 5 9 10 11 30 }

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_count:nnN { nV }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \test #1#2#3
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \int_eval:n { #2 } }
  \regex_count:nVN { \b \u{l_tmpa_tl} \b } #1 \l_tmpa_int
  \int_set_eq:cN {c@#3} \l_tmpa_int
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setcounter{testx}{4}
\test{\teststr}{\value{testx}}{testy}
\showthe\value{testy}

\setcounter{testx}{1}
\test{\teststr}{\value{testx}}{testy}
\showthe\value{testy}

\def\teststr{ 1 2 3 4 5 9 10 11 30 1}
\test{\teststr}{\value{testx}}{testy}
\showthe\value{testy}

\stop
```

In the console you get

```
> 1.
<recently read> \c@testy

l.20 \showthe\value{testy}

?
> 1.
<recently read> \c@testy

l.24 \showthe\value{testy}

?
> 2.
<recently read> \c@testy

l.28 \showthe\value{testy}
```

Comment: Thanks @egreg. It does the job.I forgot to mention that It would never happen that the string contains repeated numbers... so the first occurrence will be sufficient to store `1` on the counter provided via the third argument. Thank you!